# Get Hours and Minutes from Datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

Out Time :
2013-03-08 15:00:00.000

In Time :
2013-03-08 11:21:03.290

I need to get **Hours** and **Minutes** separately for same date from above, when **(Out Time - In Time)**.

How can I do that ?

Comment: You mean, how many Hours and Minutes have passed, between In and Out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you probably just want:

```
TimeSpan difference = outTime - inTime;
int hours = (int) difference.TotalHours;
int minutes = difference.Minutes;
```

Note that `Minutes` will give you "just the minutes (never more than 59)" whereas `TotalHours` (truncated towards zero) will give you "the total number of hours" which might be more than 23 if the times are more than a day apart.

You should also consider what you want to do if the values are negative - either consider it, or explicitly rule it out by validating against it.

Comment: Thanks for Great answer with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The `Subtract` method on the `DateTime` class will allow you subtract that date from the other date.

It will give you a `TimeSpan` which will be the difference.

I'll leave it to you to work out the actual code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/8ysw4sby.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hours property  and Minutes

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.hour.aspx