# What is the most efficient way to check that a given DateTime is on the hour?

Tags: c#

I have System.DateTime object which I need to confirm is on the hour.

So what would be the most efficient way of checking this?

The current solution that I have thought of involves converting the object ToString() and obtaining the minutes/seconds section to see if they equal zero. If there are easier ways to do this I would appreciate suggestions!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Hours and Minutes from Datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414599/get-hours-and-minutes-from-datetime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime` has [minute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [seconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.second%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties, you could directly check that, no need to convert. You could do the same for milliseconds, if that is relevant to you.

Comment: what about milliseconds.

Comment: @DanielA.White made a change

Answer (score 2):

You could go this way with highest accuracy.

```
if(date.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerHour == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

My personal solution would be to create a new `DateTime` which is on the hour and compare it with the one I wish to check, something like:

```
public bool IsOnHour(DateTime dateTime)
{
    var onHour = dateTime.Date + TimeSpan.FromHours(dateTime.Hour);

    return onHour == dateTime;
}
```

Then I don't need to check the `Minutes`, `Seconds`, `Milliseconds` etc.

Comment: Why not `dateTime.Date` instead of `dateTime - dateTime.TimeOfDay`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: `if(DateTime.Now.Minute == 0 && DateTime.Now.Second == 0 && DateTime.Now.Millisecond == 0)`

Edit: comments

Comment: what about `Datetime.Second` ?

Comment: what about milliseconds?

Comment: You cannot chain those comparisons together like that.  It results in a comparison of a `bool` to an `int` and will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a programatic way:

```
DateTime min = new DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, value.Day, value.Hour, 0, 0);
DateTime max = min.AddMinutes(1);

if (min <= value && value < max)
```

This intentionally looses precision  so that 12:59:00.000 is the same as 12:59:27.198.

Answer (score 0):

Try following .

```
var dt = new DateTime();
if (dt.Minute == 0 && dt.Second == 0 && dt.Millisecond == 0)
```